# on form submit send id using js function to the mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have mvc razor view form which on submit form calls javascript function which then sends particular selected comboboxid to the controller to further processing.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="submitForm()"/>
function submitForm()
{
    var selComboBoxId = $('#comboboxId').val();        
    // send selComboBoxId to the controller ..
}
```

is there better way to send this id on form submit, without this js function?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  You have a solution that you want to know is right, but you haven't described the problem you are trying to solve.  Why are you using javascript at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
 <input name="comboboxId" type="text" id="comboboxId">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var params = $(this).serialize();
 console.log(params);
 // do your ajax here
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zuhuroni/1/edit)